# Datatable option results in "Missing operand after 's' operator" error

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable and I want to filter this table with a company name. But it gave this error:

> Syntax error: Missing operand after 's' operator.

My code is like this:

```
DataRow[] rowList = resultDt.Select(string.Format(" [{0}] = '{1}'", resultDt.Columns["Company"], "Dyn's"));
```

What is be the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is "`Dyn's`". Can you use `\'` instead of `'`? That apostrophe is why the problem is occurring.

Comment: I think you can algo write @"Dyn's"

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, to indicate it a string literal.

Answer (score 7):

It's the apostrophe in the name, you need to escape it:

```
DataRow[] rowList = resultDt.Select(string.Format(" [{0}] = '{1}'", resultDt.Columns["Company"], "Dyn\'s"))
```

The issue is it's being substituted for `{1}` and so the resulting string looks like `'Dyn's'`, escaping it gets you to `'Dyn\'s'` which should be okay.

Answer (score 5):

```
Dyn's
```

You need to escape the apostrophe:

```
Dyn\'s
```

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping ':

```
"Dyn\'s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use LINQ to DataTable instead? I've always thought that `DataTable.Select()` is an error-prone way of doing things, precisely for this sort of reason.

Querying using LINQ to Objects (effectively) via the `DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()` method (or more simply using strongly typed data sets, IIRC) is nicer IMO. Admittedly you won't get the benefit of any in-memory indexing performed by the `DataTable`, but I suspect in the majority of cases that will be irrelevant.